# Contrary motion still sounds good: Guess the book

Tags: knowledge

There are a lot of books that talk about things like this,

where there are two people who are "chosen", and they're kind of opposites,

So I guess that opposites is actually a good thing to write a book about.

Some Ideas Never Fail,

especially when it comes to writing.

In this book, there's a

benevolent tyrant,

an insane old man,

a girl,

and a boy,

who are opposites, but still work well together.

Note:

Despite my past riddles, this is NOT a series that I've already written about… Also not sure bout the wordplay tag.

Comment: What is the question? Guess the book?

Comment: Since you're a fantasy-novel buff, what do you think of [this puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11537/the-2015th-question-on-puzzling-se)? Every number except one has been found correctly - maybe you can fix the one mistake in alexwlchan's and Michael Edenfield's answers? :-)

Comment: If there are a lot of books with these characters and themes, doesn't that mean there are lots of equally-good answers?

Comment: @AE , good point. My answer below was given without knowing about the answer which was added later. Both answers match the clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book (series) is

> The Secrets of the Immortal Nicholas Flamel.

*There are a lot of books that talk about things like this,*

> Yeah, it's a common fantasy trope.

*where there are two people who are "chosen", and they're kind of opposites,*

> The Twins of Legend: silver and gold; one to save the world, one to destroy it.

*So I guess that opposites is actually a god thing to write a book about.*

*Some Ideas Never Fail,*

*especially when it comes to writing.*

> More about how it's a common trope.

*In this book, there's a*

*benevolent tyrant,*

> Aten was the overlord of Danu Talis, a tyrant in some ways, Macchiavelli's Elder master, but actually not a Dark Elder.

*an insane old man,*

> Nicholas Flamel?

*a girl,*

> Sophie Newman.

*and a boy,*

> Josh Newman.

*who are opposites, but still work well together.*

> They stay together almost all the way through the books until the very end, when he destroys a world and she saves another. (Not too spoilery, I hope! It was certainly one of the best endings I've read - especially < SPOILER > Josh's transformation < /SPOILER > - although the books did lack something in consistency.)

I actually guessed beforehand that this was going be the subject of the OP's next riddle, having had a look at her profile page. This is the first puzzle on SE that I could have answered *pre-emptively* before it was even posted!

Comment: Aww snap, ninja'd

Comment: I suppose it WAS too easy...

Comment: @GracelynRioux Only given that I'd already guessed what the answer to your next riddle would be! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Hunger Games
>  Katniss Everdeen and Peeta Mellark are "chosen" to fight to the Death (Some Ideas Never Fail == this concept is very common) . . . . "still work well together" == both survive . . . .

MORE INFO :

> benevolent tyrant == Haymitch Abernathy
>  insane old man == President Coriolanus Snow